# Android Chip view doesn't capitalize letters with android:textAllCaps="true"

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

I've got `Chip` inflated dynamically and added to `ChipGroup`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:letterSpacing="0.02"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="#515968"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="#00000000"
    app:chipCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:chipStrokeColor="#a6aab1"
    app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"/>
```

which does not capitalize letters via `android:textAllCaps="true"`

[image: Non-capitalized]

`Chip` inherits from `TextView` so it should work.
https://material.io/components/chips/#action-chips doesn't show capitalized example, although I don't see any reason why not.

What a mistake could I made? I don't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, that `textAllCaps` does work, but... programatically.

```
viewHolder.someProviders.addView((LayoutInflater.from(viewHolder.someProviders.context)
    .inflate(R.layout.name_of_layout, viewHolder.someProviders, false) as Chip)
    .apply {
        text = provider.name
        isAllCaps = true
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `android:textAppearance` attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:textAppearance="@style/textAllCaps"
    android:text="AllCaps"
    .../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="textAllCaps" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

**Note:** This requires a minimum of version **1.2.0-alpha03**